# CSS is not updating in browser instanly

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I am having this problem for long time. Whenever I update my existing `stylesheet` it not take effect in browser instantly. If I view page source and click on my stylesheet, ex:`<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/stylesheets/theme-custom.css">` recently added codes are not shown. It updates after few hours. This happens both in `Firefox` & `Chrome`.

Why this happening? And how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to performance reasons browser cache loaded css files. So if you update your css you have to clear your cache. You can also reload the page with clearing it by pressing `CTRL + R`.

At the following linked page you can find approaches how to deliver your css and force browsers to get the current version (like adding timestamps or anything else as parameter):
https://css-tricks.com/can-we-prevent-css-caching/

EDIT:
You can also just disable the caching completely in the settings or developer tools of your browser.

Comment: I don't want to disable caching, it may drain my browser performance. But your link help me a lot. Thank you so much. This is a great idea.

Comment: You are welcome :-) Also note the hint at the bottom regarding your live system -> adding a version param is by far better in production :-) In development of cause you do not want any css caching :-)